# Javascript and PHP to generate "live" print preview

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, printing, preview

I want to be able to enter data and use Javascript onChange/onBlur/etc to render a "live" print preview; with page breaks. The ultimate goal is to have a PDF file that can be saved/emailed/etc that will be identical to the "preview". The data is to be stored in a MySQL database, I'm figuring AJAX to write it while entry.

Has anyone heard of a library (ideally free; purchase is an option) that can do this?  If not, can you point me towards what can help me write something?

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of PDF creation libraries for the PHP, you can easily google it.
http://www.fpdf.org/ for example

Comment: I'm looking for more than just the PDF library. I need the "live" print preview before the PDF is generated.

Comment: Why don't you want to use PDF itself as a preview?

Comment: @Alex: With the state of the art technology, you have to go through PDF previews. Otherwise you could write your own rendering engine, which is too painful and is worth for small projects.